# Docker Hub image that can run Ansible playbooks

Tags: docker, ansible

I am just getting started using Ansible and would like to try and run a playbook inside of a GitLab CI/CD job. However, I'm just finding out that the ansible/ansible image on the Docker Hub does not contain ansible-playbook. I'm getting cross-eyed looking at all of the unofficial ones out there, and I'm not sure what to pick. Can someone point me to an easy/readily-available Docker image I could pull that contains ansible-playbook just so that I can experiment? I'd prefer not to have to set up a whole separate Dockerfile etc. just to get started playing around.

Answer (score 2):

Just build your own. Your `Dockerfile` could be as simple as:

```
FROM python:3.9
RUN pip install ansible
```

You say " I'd prefer not to have to set up a whole separate Dockerfile etc", but I don't think that adds much complexity. Update as necessary for Python or Ansible dependencies that are appropriate to your particular playbooks.